# Convert MS Access 2010 query to SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, ms-access

I have a query in MS Access database. I want to run this query in SQLite database. I wondering whether there is a easy way to convert the code or just change step by step?

Comment: you should really consider posting the MS Access query if you want any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options available for viewing the contents of a sqlite database and running queries against it. When building sqlite from source you can choose to build the shell utility.

If you want something more turnkey you can install a free tool such as [Sqlite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) for Firefox or [Sqlite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/).

In both apps you can copy-and-paste your SQL that you want to execute against a SQLITE database file. Good luck!